# Django send email from POST form

Tags: django

I am trying to set up a send email form on my site but am having some issues connecting data filled out on the website to my `contact` action.

I can see in the logs (after I click send) that there is a successful `200` response from a call to `contact/send`.

`POST /contact/send/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7665`

But I cannot see my debugging `print(request)` being triggered.

Am I implementing this correctly or where do I need to change my config?

`contact.py`

```
def contact(request):

    print(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            try:
                send_email(subject, message, email, [f'{os.getenv("EMAIL_ADDRESS")}'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

`contact/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('send/', views.index, name='contact')
]
```

Contact form

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Content
        ============================================= -->
        <section id="content">

            <div class="content-wrap">

                <div class="container clearfix">

                    <!-- Postcontent
                    ============================================= -->
                    <div class="postcontent nobottommargin">

                        <h3>Send us an Email</h3>

                        <div class="form-widget">

                            <div class="form-result"></div>

                            <form class="nobottommargin" id="template-contactform" name="template-contactform" action="send/" method="post">

                            {% csrf_token %}

                                <div class="form-process"></div>

                                <div class="col_one_third">
                                    <label for="template-contactform-name">Name <small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="template-contactform-name" value="" class="sm-form-control required" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_one_third">
                                    <label for="template-contactform-email">Email <small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="email" id="template-contactform-email" name="template-contactform-email" value="" class="required email sm-form-control" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="clear"></div>

                                <div class="col_two_third">
                                    <label for="template-contactform-subject">Subject <small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="template-contactform-subject" name="subject" value="" class="required sm-form-control" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="clear"></div>

                                <div class="col_full">
                                    <label for="template-contactform-message">Message <small>*</small></label>
                                    <textarea class="required sm-form-control" id="template-contactform-message" name="template-contactform-message" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_full hidden">
                                    <input type="text" id="template-contactform-botcheck" name="template-contactform-botcheck" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_full">
                                    <button class="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="template-contactform-submit" name="template-contactform-submit" value="submit">Send Message</button>
                                </div>

                                <input type="hidden" name="prefix" value="template-contactform-"> 


                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- .postcontent end -->

                    <!-- Sidebar
                    ============================================= -->
                    <div class="sidebar col_last nobottommargin">

                        <div class="widget noborder notoppadding">

                            <a href="https://twitter.com/RealizeSec" target="_blank" class="social-icon si-small si-dark si-twitter">
                                <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
                                <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
                            </a>

                        </div>

                    </div><!-- .sidebar end -->

                </div>

            </div>

        </section><!-- #content end -->
{% endblock  %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contact/urls.py is incorrect, trigger `views.contact` for `send/` instead of views.index

Corrected contact/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('send/', views.contact, name='contact')
]
```